# Why doesn't an Ubuntu patch baseline allow auto-approval delay?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I noticed that among the default patch baselines that AWS provides for Systems Manager (SSM) Patch Manager, the Ubuntu patch baseline doesn't seem to support an auto-approval delay.  Most of the other operating system patch baselines have an auto-approval delay such as

[image]

I even tried creating my own Ubuntu patch baseline in a CloudFormation template where I specified ApproveAfterDays

[image]

CloudFormation created it without error, but there is no Auto approval delay on the new baseline.

Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for an explanation, I found this tidbit in [a documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-patch-baselines.html#patch-manager-baselines-pre-defined):

> There is no wait before approval because reliable release dates aren't
> available in the repositories.

The same applies to a couple other operating systems as well.  So it seems CloudFormation just ignores the setting for some operating systems.

Comment: answering off-topic questions just encourages more of them.

Comment: I removed the "Ubuntu" tag (assuming that was what you felt was off topic) but I do still wonder why Ubuntu repositories don't have "reliable release dates" that AWS can rely upon.